# Deployed Rails 4 to Heroku , received error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have finished a rails 4 sample project, it runs perfect locally , but after i pushed up app to Heroku, it didn't  work as expected .

details:

`An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.`

I checked the `heroku logs`, have no idea. but i guess it's something related to unicorn according to the log. Any one can help? i would be very appreciated!

Databse.yml file

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: devep00

test:
  <<: *default
  database: testp00
```

Comment: did you precompile before pushing to Heroku ? - Pierre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to have a config file for Unicorn, please create a file with following content and put it in `config/unicorn.rb`

```
# config/unicorn.rb
worker_processes Integer(ENV["WEB_CONCURRENCY"] || 3)
timeout 15
preload_app true

before_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT'
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

More details here
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn#config

Answer (score 0):

As @charinten has pointed out - Post this in your unicorn.rb file under config , if you don't have one already (Saw the answer after i posted mine)

```
worker_processes 4
timeout 30
preload_app true

before_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT'
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```